# How can show device primary contact viewer to show ONE contact with phone number

Tags: android, android-contacts

I'm writing an app and I need to show a contact to user. I have the phone number and I can make a query to get the contact detail. Like this:

```
ContentResolver cr = context.getContentResolver();
    Uri uri = Uri.withAppendedPath(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.CONTENT_FILTER_URI,
            Uri.encode(phoneNumber));
    Cursor cursor = cr.query(uri,
            new String[]{ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME}, null, null, null);
    if (cursor == null) {
        return null;
    }
    String contactName = phoneNumber;
    if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
        contactName = cursor.getString(cursor
                .getColumnIndex(ContactsContract.PhoneLookup.DISPLAY_NAME));
    }
```

BUT I need to show the DEVICE primary contact viewer and I do't know How?

Like this:

[image]

Comment: This is all documented here: https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html in chapter "Contacts/People App"

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski Thank you for your reply . But unfortunately I can not access to your link , nor google documents also in my area !!

Comment: Impressive. I posted reply with related quotes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all documented in official Android docs, [Common Intents](https://developer.android.com/guide/components/intents-common.html), chapter "Contacts/People App".

**EDIT**

> But unfortunately I can not access to your link , nor google documents also in my area !!

Here're quotes from linked docs:

**View a contact**

To display the details for a known contact, use the ACTION_VIEW action and specify the contact with a content: URI as the intent data.

There are primarily two ways to initially retrieve the contact's URI:

- Use the contact URI returned by the ACTION_PICK, shown in the previous section (this approach does not require any app permissions).
- Access the list of all contacts directly, as described in Retrieving a List of Contacts (this approach requires the READ_CONTACTS permission).

Example:

```
public void viewContact(Uri contactUri) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, contactUri);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

**Edit an existing contact**

To edit a known contact, use the ACTION_EDIT action, specify the contact with a content: URI as the intent data, and include any known contact information in extras specified by constants in ContactsContract.Intents.Insert.

There are primarily two ways to initially retrieve the contact URI:

- Use the contact URI returned by the ACTION_PICK, shown in the previous section (this approach does not require any app permissions).
- Access the list of all contacts directly, as described in Retrieving a List of Contacts (this approach requires the READ_CONTACTS permission).

Note: Extras - One or more of the extras defined in ContactsContract.Intents.Insert so you can populate fields of the contact details.

```
public void editContact(Uri contactUri, String email) {
    Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_EDIT);
    intent.setData(contactUri);
    intent.putExtra(Intents.Insert.EMAIL, email);
    if (intent.resolveActivity(getPackageManager()) != null) {
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

For more information about how to edit a contact, read [Modifying Contacts Using Intents](https://developer.android.com/training/contacts-provider/modify-data.html).

Comment: Thanks @MarcinOrlowski. You are a light in the night.